# What is the best option to upload a big image file (about 70MB) from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, html

A client asked me to create a cropper and I used the great plugin from https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Once the image is uploaded and cropped the user can see a preview in the actual page (the image data is stored in a hidden as base64 encoded text), then send the form and wait for the images to be uploaded (up to 5 minutes depending on your connection speed).

My client asked me a way to "defer the load" so the user could finish the buying process while the image is loading.

My unique idea is to open a pop-up window and send there the text to upload while the user finishes the process.

Is there a better option to do that? It is possible to do what I want?

Comment: both of them requires that the user is on page A until the process is finished, what I want is to let the user plays for the whole site while the file is uploading.

Comment: Saving data to the local storage will avoid having to reload. Using a Single Page Application will also eliminate the need to re-download the image.

Comment: Local Storages has the limit of 10MB (5MB in most browsers). The site is WordPress so it is impossible to use a Single Page App

Comment: Frameset's main or frame page and reload main page in different frame ? Also Geasmonkey browser extension may help, but quite complicated to install by all users, but quite handy tool. And would tell in case you open window and reload page, it is hard to keep handle to that popup - opening another of same name may help, but CORS block may occur then. So can end-up as a orphan - this is reason why I love HTA, Cordova or node.js concepts...

Comment: Or you can open that next user page by script - Ajax load and display in/change an element ?

Comment: Loading the whole page over this one needs extra work. But I get your point about the orphan popup. Perhaps I can let the popup to take care of the uploading and notify the user via email when the file is ready